# How to plot 3 graphs side by side in the same plot | python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to plot 3 graphs in continuous matter so where the line of the first plot ends, I want the line of the second plot to start, and where the second one ends, I want third one to continue.

Since I have 3 subplots I want to plot them one after other in one line.

This is my code, but it plots them separately:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1) # two axes on figure
ax1.plot(max_1_season.index, base_1_season.r_base,'r')
ax2.plot(max_2_season.index, base_2_season.r_base, 'b')
ax3.plot(max_3_season.index, base_3_season.r_base, 'g')

plt.savefig('plot.png', dpi=600)
plt.show()
```

Based on values I have, I know that there should be rising curve after each season, so I know they do continue one after other (take look at x axis).

As seen on the picture below, how can I merge them together?

[picture of plotting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWKBc.png)

Comment: Maybe [`sharex=True`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a x-axis vector for each plot, in a continuous manner with `np.linspace`.

Such as:

```
ax1 = np.random.randn(10)
ax2 = np.random.randn(10)
ax3 = np.random.randn(10)

y1 = np.linspace(1,10,10)
y2 = np.linspace(11,20,10)
y3 = np.linspace(21,30,10)

plt.plot(y1, ax1, 'r') 
plt.plot(y2, ax2, 'b') 
plt.plot(y3, ax3, 'g') 
plt.show()
```

[image]